# <select> dropdown list scroll not working for touch screens in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have a web application running on a touch screen device (windows 8.1). And i'm displaying a list of cities in a select tag in the following way.

```
<select ng-model="selectedCity" class="textInputSeeThrough ui-keyboard-input  ui-corner-all ui-keyboard-autoaccepted" style="overflow: overlay !important; height:46px; color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.56); text-align: center; text-align-last: center;">
    <option value="" disabled selected style="color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.56); text-align: center;">--- SELECT YOUR CITY ---</option>
    <option ng-repeat="ttl in cities" value="{{ttl}}" style="background-color: black; color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.56);" >{{ttl}}</option>
</select>
```

But when i try to scroll this dropdown list, it does not work. However since chrome uses user agent style sheets i found out that chrome applies the `

```
overflow: visible !important;
```

So i tried overriding this from chrome developer tools and the following style did the job.

```
overflow: overlay !important;
```

But after i did the change permanently in my source code and re-deployed the application it stopped working. How do i resolve this? Any workarounds are welcome. TIA.

Comment: have you tried using overflow-y : scroll?

Comment: @Akshaypadwal yes i tried doing that. Doesn't work

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kyrcha/ULSy3/6/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=ULSy3

Comment: @Purushothaman this looks like a promising workaround. I'm looking to do this without using an input box. I'll keep it as a last resort. Any idea why the scroll doesn't work on touch? This example works on touch screen.

Comment: check the answer @k9yosh